# Insert Muliple Rows in Categories Cross Table but with same Auto Increment ID

Tags: php, mysql

I am an amateur hobbying a video site, where users can submit video urls. Everything works, but now I want multiple categories to be able to be selected for one same video. Categories are stored in seperate tables. I am sure you will understand from the code:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO videos 
(title, source, thumb_large, author, email_by) VALUES('$title', '$video_url', '$thumb_url', '$author', '$email') ") or die(mysql_error());  
mysql_query("INSERT INTO videos_categories 
(category_id) VALUES('$category_name_id') ") or die(mysql_error());
```

What I want to do is to add another category for the same video ID the tables are both on AUTO INCREMENT synced with each other at the moment:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO videos_categories (category_id) VALUES('$category_name_id_two') ") or die(mysql_error());
```

The variable is currently registered as:

```
$category_name_id = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['category_id']));
```

And is currently selected through dropdown (select with name: category_id) and it works fine. However, I want to change this ofcourse into select boxes, so mulitple, or upto 3 categories can be selected, instead of having 3 dropdown menus.

I hope you can help me out with this, I am stuck here.

Edit:
I wanted to add that there are three tables, one from which categories are retrieved, one that stores the video_id+category_id which should make at possible to have multiple categories per video, and one with the videos.

Thanks

Comment: you cannot have same auto increment value for multiple entries. Add another field for comparison other than auto increment field and use that one for comparison. Keep auto increment field as the primary key so that if you want to delete one entry it will be useful .

Comment: You should not call `htmlspecialchars()` when querying the database. That should only be used when displaying results on a web page.

Comment: After inserting into `videos`, use `mysql_insert_id()` to get the ID assigned to that video. You can then use this when creating the relationship with categories in the `videos_categories` value.

Comment: @Damodaran How should I work this out? I was thinking myself to remove auto_increment from the videos_categories table, then somehow during the insert process retrieve the ID of the inserted row in the videos table, then take that ID and add a row for each selected genre in the videos_categories table. But how, I dont know.

Comment: @Barmar Funny! I was just thinking this after reading the comments, see my previous comment, how to proceed? Shall I first remove auto_increment from the videos_categories table structure itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to change the select box to something like this:

```
<select name="category_id[]" multiple="multiple">
     <!-- Options -->
</select>
```

...

In backend, After this query:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO videos 
(title, source, thumb_large, author, email_by) VALUES('$title', '$video_url', 
'$thumb_url', '$author', '$email') ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Do:

```
$video_id = mysql_insert_id();
$categories = $_POST['category_id'];
$values = '';
foreach($categories as $category_id) {
     $values .= "('$video_id', '$category_id'),";
}
$values = rtrim($values, ',');
$query = "INSERT INTO videos_categories(video_id,category_id) VALUES $values";
mysql_query($query);
```

Few Suggestions:

Since mysql_* apis are deprecated, please don't use them. Switch to mysqli.
Do the validation and sanitization of the data before using in sql queires.

Comment: Thanks so much for your input, however there is still a problem: INSERT into the videos table goes fine. However, no data at all is inserted into the video_categories table. I mean none at all. No matter if I select only one or two or three options. What are your thoughts? I feel like this is very close.

Comment: I have the feeling that problem lies here: foreach($categories as $category) {.. What is the functoin of 'as' $category in particular? I don't see it come back anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your response again. Now when I select one, it works fine, but when I select two or more, nothing is inserted into the videos_categories table (not even a single row).

Comment: echo $query and check

Comment: When I select one option then (works fine): 
INSERT INTO vines_categories(vine_id,category_id) VALUES ('39', '2')

But when I select two then (nothing inserted in actual table):
INSERT INTO vines_categories(vine_id,category_id) VALUES ('40', '2'),('40', '13').

I double-checked the table and it appeared that I had PRIMARY and UNIQUE VALUE selected on video_id, I removed it and it works.